# How to Initialize HashMap correctly

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm not sure if I did this HashMap correct but I am stuck!! I'm suppose to declare

1. An instance variable of type Map that maps Items to GameObjects.
2. Initialise the map in the constructor using a HashMap and place the four game-objects in it.
3. Use map to simplify the methods getName, getLocation, and getSound.

I need help with understanding how to do all 3 correctly.

```
package river;

public class GameEngine {

public enum Item {
    TOP, MID, BOTTOM, PLAYER;
}

public enum Location {
    START, FINISH, BOAT;
}


private GameObject top;
private GameObject mid;
private GameObject bottom;
private GameObject player;

private Location currentLocation;

public GameEngine() {
    top = new Wolf();
    mid = new Goose();
    bottom = new Beans();
    player = new Farmer();
    currentLocation = Location.START;
}

//Declare an instance variable of type Map that maps Items to GameObjects

 Map<Item, GameObject> itemMap = createMap(){
 private static Map<Item, GameObject> itemMap = new HashMap<>();
   itemMap.put(Item.TOP, top);
   itemMap.put(Item.MID, mid);
   itemMap.put(Item.BOTTOM, bottom);
   itemMap.put(Item.PLAYER, player);
   return itemMap;
 }

//Initialize the map in a constructor using a HashMap

  ???

// use map to simplify the methods (getName, getLocation, getSound)
public String getName(Item id) {
    switch (id) {
    case TOP:
        return top.getName();
    case MID:
        return mid.getName();
    case BOTTOM:
        return bottom.getName();
    default:
        return player.getName();
    }
}

public Location getLocation(Item id) {
    switch (id) {
    case TOP:
        return top.getLocation();
    case MID:
        return mid.getLocation();
    case BOTTOM:
        return bottom.getLocation();
    default:
        return player.getLocation();
    }
}

public String getSound(Item id) {
    switch (id) {
    case TOP:
        return top.getSound();
    case MID:
        return mid.getSound();
    case BOTTOM:
        return bottom.getSound();
    default:
        return player.getSound();
    }
}


public Location getCurrentLocation() {
    return currentLocation;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure if I did this HashMap correct

You will find that the compiler is unhappy with this.

```
 Map<Item, GameObject> itemMap = createMap(){
 private static Map<Item, GameObject> itemMap = new HashMap<>();
   itemMap.put(Item.TOP, top);
   itemMap.put(Item.MID, mid);
   itemMap.put(Item.BOTTOM, bottom);
   itemMap.put(Item.PLAYER, player);
   return itemMap;
 }
```

The initialization expression *resembles* a cross between a method call, and an anonymous class.  But it is actually either completely invalid or unworkable.  (Is `createMap` declared anywhere?  As what?)

I suspect that you might be trying to use the "initialization a map with an anonymous class" idiom:

```
 Map<Item, GameObject> itemMap = new HashMap<>() {{
     put(Item.TOP, top);
     put(Item.MID, mid);
     put(Item.BOTTOM, bottom);
     put(Item.PLAYER, player);
 }};
```

It is cute, and concise ... but it uses an obscure Java language feature and is therefore probably a bad idea.  (Many Java programmers won't understand it.)

What the above actually does is to declare an anonymous subclass of HashMap that uses an instance initializer block to populate the instance before returning it.

(Have you even heard of an instance initializer block?  Many Java programmers haven't!  And you probably won't be taught it.)

It is almost equivalent to this:

```
Map<Item, GameObject> itemMap = new HashMap<>();
itemMap.put(Item.TOP, top);
itemMap.put(Item.MID, mid);
itemMap.put(Item.BOTTOM, bottom);
itemMap.put(Item.PLAYER, player);
```

To my mind, this is a much better way to write it.  (Don't be cute :-) )

Comment: I'm not a java programmer so this is new to me. the code above is what I used from an example about HashMaps as Map<Item, GameObject> itemMap = new HashMap<>(); is something I am supposed to use.. I get syntax errors when I use the put method so I can't compile if it's wrong.

Comment: Well, look at the updated version of my answer for the better way to write it .... and compare it with what you wrote.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood the example, but if it *actually* said to initialize the map like what was in your code, it is nonsense.

Comment: I think my complier hates me cause I have updated my code with your suggestion and all I get is Syntax error, insert "Identifier (" to complete MethodHeaderName

Comment: now if I do                                                                                                               static Map<Item, GameObject> itemMap = new HashMap<>();
static { itemMap.put(Item.TOP, top);
itemMap.put(Item.MID, mid);
itemMap.put(Item.BOTTOM, bottom);
itemMap.put(Item.PLAYER, player);                                                                                    }                                                                                                                                            Then I'm clear to work on using my map in one of my getters

Comment: I see.  The initialization code needs to be inside the constructor for GameEngine.  (And that's what your requirements say too.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206953/discussion-between-mscr3ole-and-stephen-c).